# Does MATLAB support double integration on single variable numerically?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, integral

I have a long vector

```
acceleration=[6.45, 6.50, 6.52, 6.32, .... , 4.75]
```

Already obtained from a simulink (takes a very long time to run the simulink model again). And assume the step time is constant `dt=0.1`

Is there any way to find the final position numerically?

I know there is a [trapz](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html) function an I know that MATLAB supports 2D [integration](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html) and I know that integration inside simulink is an option. However, is there any way to take double integration:

```
final_position= integrate integrate acceleration dt^2
```

Numerically, with a precision not worse than trapezoidal method?

I prefer to avoid loop based solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the trapezoidal rule:

```
vinit = 0;                                    % initial velocity
pinit = 0;                                    % initial position

velocity = zeros(size(acceleration)) + vinit; % velocity vector
position = zeros(size(acceleration)) + pinit; % position vector

velocity(2:end) = velocity(2:end) + 0.5 * dt * cumsum(acceleration(2:end)+acceleration(1:end-1));
position(2:end) = position(2:end) + 0.5 * dt * cumsum(    velocity(2:end)+    velocity(1:end-1));
```

I'm using `cumsum()` (cumulative sum) to calculate the integral at each point, not just the overall sum; this means that the velocity can be integrated again to get the position. The final position is obviously `position(end)`.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that in-place operators don't exist in MATLAB.  I took the liberty in editing your post.  They do, however, exist in Octave, and I suspect you developed the above code in Octave then placed it here. Be mindful of the tags before you start answering MATLAB / Octave related questions.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a built in function that does what you want. My suggestion would be to build your own. The function `trapz` is taking the integral along the entire domain and hence gives you one value. Since you want to take the second integral you first need to produce a vector of values that correspond to the first integral. This is accomplished by integrating increasingly large steps of the original vector.

```
acceleration = [6.45, 6.50, 6.52, 6.32, .... , 4.75];
velocity = zeros(size(acceleration));
for i = 1:length(acceleration),
    velocity(i) = trapz(acceleration(1:i))*dt;
end
p = trapz(velocity)*dt;
```

I know this uses a loop but maybe it can help you get started. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to turn your second order differential equation into a first order one.

Your equation is

```
X''(t) = a(t);
X(0) = x_0;
X'(0) = x_p_0;
```

Now if you define `u1(t) = X(t); u2(t) = X'(t)`, you will get

```
U'(t) = A*U(t) + a(t)
```

where

```
U(t) = [u1(t);u2(t)]
A = [0 1
     0 0]
```

Then you can use any solver (say ode45)  to solve this U(t) vector. The second component of the vector is the position. It's error bounds is much smaller than trapz like functions. Also matlab has many optimizations inside the solvers they implemented.